# How to Check for an Enterprise Provisioning Profile on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, enterprise

I know that iPhones with enterprise provisioning profiles installed send massive amounts of data back to the company that added the profile.  This includes your text messages, phone records, and internet history.

How do I check if one of these profiles has been installed?  I have an iPhone that I think a profile was installed on, but I see no indication anywhere in settings that this is true.

Comment: For clarification, do you see any profiles listed in the *Profiles* section of *Settings*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Settings -> General and scroll all the way to the bottom. At the very bottom is "Reset". Above that is "Regulatory". Above that is "Profiles". If you have no profiles installed, this may not show up. In that case, you're fine. If a profile does come up click on it to get more information. The information page will tell you the name of the profile and who it's licensed to, like this:
[image: Profile example]

Comment: Thanks!  Is there any way to get from that exactly what data the profile allows them to collect, or should I just assume the worst once one is installed?

Comment: @ebrts in "more details" you should be able to see what the profile can access. For example, this profile can only access "Internal Settings"

Comment: so if my profile has the right to 'Add Configuration Profiles' then I guess I'm pretty much toast, right? (since they could always add whatever they want later)

Comment: @ebrts well you'll be able to see any profiles they add. If you don't have any other profiles added, then you're good for now